# Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin'

Tags: java, android, gradle, plugins

When trying to sync my android project with gradle I have the following error :

```
Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

And :

```
Build file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\android\android-anpr-master\app\build.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find implementation class 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin' for plugin 'com.android.application' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/aprotiere/.gradle/caches/jars-9/f84232a270d8a27731cbe96e1da64c89/gradle-8.1.2.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.android.application.properties.
```

Here is my build.gradle (app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.DVLA.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        //noinspection OldTargetApi,EditedTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false // You can enable minification if needed
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://maven2.javacv.googlecode.com/git/' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation ':1.6.1' // Use the latest version
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.12.5' // Update the version of Joda-Time
    implementation files('libs/javacpp.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javacv.jar')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':libraries:opencv') // Make sure the project path is correct

}
```

build.gradle (project) :

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

If you need any missing information please let me know. I can provide logs and other files like gradle-wrapper.properties but I don't want the post to be so long unless it's needed.

Thanks